# How to store LAST_INSERT_ID() in database as foreign key in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I Have requirement is, there are two tables users and student.

```
user table                          student table
id | email | user_type_id               id |    email   |name |user_id
```

when student submit the form data should be inserted in both table .and in user table,i m storing user_type_id =1 static but in student table in user_id column , generated  user id should be save.

i m not able to save user id in students table . this is code i have tried

students model

```
public function add($data)
    {

        $temp = array(
            'Email' => $data['Email'],
            'user_type_id'=> 1
        );

        return $this->db->insert('users',$temp);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
        return $this->db->insert('students',$data);
    }
```

Comment: you can use triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

[$this->db->insert_id()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

public function add($data)
    {

```
    $temp = array(
        'Email' => $data['Email'],
        'user_type_id'=> 1
    );

    return $this->db->insert('users',$temp);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    $data['user_id'] = $this->db->insert_id(); // Use insert_id()
    return $this->db->insert('students',$data);
}
```

Comment: Voting up is different from choosing answer as solution. If you see voting arrows against my answer, below it there is white right image. Just click on it, it will become green. Thats it.